# Rails: inject new list items (<li>) into an unordered list element (<ul>)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I need to take pre-formatted HTML (in the form of an unordered list, with list items) and  inject some new items before displaying it. As an example, I have data (in my database) that looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I need to inject two more items into the UL before it gets sent to the view:

```
@new_item1 = "New Item 1"
@new_item2 = "New Item 2"

#Inject new items into UL with some Rails code
#Display the following:

<ul>
  <li>New Item 1</li>
  <li>New Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  etc...
</ul>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So you already have the UL as text in the database, or is that also being constructed?

Comment: the UL is already constructed in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be just to replace `<ul>` with `<ul> + <li>@new_item1</li> + <li>@new_item2</li>`

```
s = "<ul>
       <li>Item 1</li>
       <li>Item 2</li>
       <li>Item 3</li>
     </ul>"

s.gsub!('<ul>', "<ul>\n  <li>#{@new_item1}</li>\n  <li>#{@new_item2}</li>")
```